# Permission Error when writing files in ArcGIS 10.1

Tags: python, arcgis

I have a python tool in ArcGIS 10.1 in which the output is a .txt file, however whenever I run the tool, I get a Permission Error at this line:

```
filename = 'test.txt'
o = open(filename, 'w') #<---
```

There is no existing file with that name in the dir. Is there a permission that I need to include within the arcgis side of the tool?

Comment: Maybe you don't have write permission in the current directory... have you tried with an absolute path to a directory where you know you can write?

Comment: It is an absolute path, and the program works just fine when run from a console

Comment: Maybe arcgis is running as a different user? Which OS are you on?

Comment: Win 8; I just tried running as an administrator and that didn't work. There is only one 'user' on the computer as well.

Comment: What Exactly is the value of filename as your example isn't an absolute path?

Comment: If you are not specifying a path, then ArcGIS is going to write to whatever directory the python subprocess started in.  It may be a protected directory.  Also I'm not sure if the admin rights automatically pass to subprocesses.